# Do I understand the principles of Hawk Auth correctly?

Tags: security, authentication, identification

I've read everything I could read about it, but there were questions.

In different implementations, I see certain differences (for example, somewhere **mac** is called **hash**, or **hash** is some other hashed string (not **mac**). And some other answers.

Next, I will describe how I understand the specification.

We have:

```
$keyId = "dh37fgj492je";
$key   = "werxhqb98rpaxn39848xrunpaw3489ruxnpa98w4rxn";`
$algo  = "hmac sha256";
$hash  = "6R4rV5iE+NPoym+WwjeHzjAGXUtLNIxmo1vpMofpLAE=";
```

When did we get this data? As I understand, we can get them at login and recorded in the database. Right or not? Next, we store this data in Cookies. Is we save all the data or just `$keyId`, `$key` and `$algo`?

Next, we form a header by the data from Cookies, which we saved.

Then we transfer this header to the address from which we want to receive information (`https://example.com/api/users/4512478`). Server returns data.

**My questions**.

- What data should be stored in the user Cookies (or LocalStorage), and what data should be stored only on the server side?
- What data from the stored is temporary, and what data is stored for some time as a *Session ID*?
- Do I need to store data in the session? Can I save Hawk data in database (*in user table*)?

Comment: Any reason why Hawk is being used ?.. you should use something which is very widely used , it will enable your solution to be hooked to strong authentication solutions with ease...

Comment: @SoumenMukherjee , I just wanted to try this solution, and I also whanted to defend against time attacks. There is no particular reason. And what do you suggest as a simpler alternative? I really would be interested.

Comment: You can go for Oauth2